# Need Help on C#.Net User Control Memory Leak. It seems system.Timer function causing leak

Tags: c#, memory-leaks, timer, user-controls

I have a C# user control created using lots of other Microsoft standard controls and its leaking memory. I have timer function and dragdrop functionality in it.

To simulate the issue i have created a simple C# user control. Other Microsoft controls like panel, treeview control, ListControl, Context Menu, tooltips, DateTimePicker are placed on it.  I have subscribed to these controls events and I am writing some text using Debug.Writeline() in  event handlers.
I have set **AllowDrop** property of these controls to true. My Timer function which runs at 1500 milliseconds interval toggles the tree view nodes and show/hide the context menu.

**My Timer Function**

```
 void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.treeView1.Nodes[0].Toggle();
            this.treeView1.Nodes[0].Nodes[0].Toggle();
            string test1 = "this 123";
            if (toggleSwitch)
            {
                this.contextMenuStrip1.Show(this, 200, 10);
            }
            else
            {
                this.contextMenuStrip1.Hide();
            }
            toggleSwitch = !toggleSwitch;
            Debug.WriteLine(test1);

            //GC.Collect();
            //GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
            //GC.Collect();
        }
```

when I run this user control in ActiveX Container or Microsoft User Control Container, I see that memory always goes up. It Stops increasing for some time, but again after some time it increases, it never reduces. It went 9 MB up in one day.

With .net Profiler i found that objects are held back DropTarget, Timer, EventHandler which are again held back by GCHandle instance. Also new instance of **Native.TrackMouseEvent** objects are created and those are also held back by DropTarget instance.

Please help me how to fix this issue. I tried calling GC.Collect in timer function but that didnt work. if i stop timer function. there is no memory leak.

**.net profiler image showing object held back by droptarget and timer**
[image: .net profiler image showing object held back by droptarget and timer]

**source code for sample is available at** [dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/s/apqunctbmith18o/ShyamUserControlLibrary.zip?dl=0) It need .snk file which i have not shared. when you run this application it will start user container.

Comment: IMHO, 9 MB increase in one day, is not likely to be a good indicator of memory leak.. The image is too small to look at as well. And, the code snippet you have also looks fairly simple, and I doubt it has anything to do directly with leak, if any.. Is it possible to add more code to the question.. may be how events and timers are being used by the control? (I have seen event handlers and timers being used in a way which can lead to generally slow leaks.)

Comment: You are surely forgetting to call the timer's Dispose() method.  It will just keep on ticking.  And keep a reference to the form with everything that lives on it.  Boilerplate fix is to drop Timer from the toolbox, that one automatically gets disposed.

Comment: hi visak, I have updated the post with source code. this is just a sample application. In my actual code i see that other classes instances are also not released because its held by timer and droptarget object. As I am not closing this control i have not called timer dispose function. I the dispose of User control i will call the timer.dispose function. you can see the image by copying image link and pasting it on the browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its not leaking the memory. I found that though memory increase after each tick but after some time it stops increasing and stay there.